# R: Randomly Draw From Groups

Tags: r

I am unsure if the title is clear, but I have a dataframe that has 1000 observations of households, some of which have one member and some of which have two members. I need to divide up the dataframe into two equal sized dataframes with the individuals from the same household not being placed in the same subset.

The dataframe functionally looks like this.

```
household <- c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8)
person <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(household,person))
df
```

Again, I need two subsets of data and person 1 from household 2 cannot be in the same as person 2 from household 2, and so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, using `ave` to split by household, you could do

```
set.seed(1234)
df$groups <- ave(df$household, df$household, FUN=function(x) sample(c("C", "T"), length(x)))
```

For each household, I sampled from `c("T", "C")` where "T" stands for treatment and "C" for control. This will ensure that your household members will be divided between groups and that the resulting sample sizes will be equal in expectation. Here, equal sample sizes happens to work out in actuality.

```
table(df$groups)
C T 
6 6
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

This might not create equal sets but does create group memberships randomly:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(household) %>% 
mutate(member=sample(c("A","B"), length(household),replace=FALSE))
```